# How do I determine convergence of the following sum using Cauchy test?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, cauchy-sequences

The sum is

$ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }2^n\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2}\: $

I started by studying the asymptotic behavior

$ 2^n\left(\frac{n}{n+1}\right)^{n^2}\:=2^n\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n\:}\right]^{-n} $

So if the following sum is convergent

$ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{2^n}/e^{n} $

I suppose I should reason that the sum under question is also convergent (am I right about this?), I guess this is just for simplification.

Then I introduce $ \varepsilon >0 $, and as I see should prove that there exists such $ N<n $ that following thing holds for all $n$ and $p$

$ \left|{2^n}/{e^n}+{2^{n+1}}/{e^{n+1}}+...+{2^{n+p}}/{2^{n+p}}\:\right|<\varepsilon $

The least thing I can do from there on is this

$ {2^n}{e^{-n}}\left|1+{2}/{e}+...+{2^p}/{2^p}\:\right|<\varepsilon $

How do I prove such $N$ exists?

Comment: You have that $2^n / e^n = (2/e)^n$, and $2/e < 1$

Comment: @vonbrand is $|a| <1$ sufficient for convergence of $a^n$ ?

Comment: Compare to the geometric series...

Comment: @vonbrand well geometric series is $0.5^n$ and this is $0.736^n$

Comment: Geometric series $\sum_{k \ge 0} a^k$ converges if and only if $\lvert a \rvert < 1$